# Injecting html via javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some mvc3 code that I'm taking ownership and there are views that both apply html helpers and html javascript injection within views.

Personally, I prefer raw html or helpers as opposed to html injection.  What are the pro's and cons of each?

**Basic html and helpers**:

```
        <div id="efI" class="ef">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div>
           @Html.ActionLink("Click here.", "SomeAction")
        </div>
```

**Injection:**:

```
    @Html.EditorForModel()  //this generates controls from above...
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#efI').append('<div>@Html.ActionLink("Click here.", "SomeAction")</div>');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really much difference in the static example you provide.  Usually injections are made with dynamically created HTML (for example,table cells managed by AJAX calls to a DB).

Comment: But why would you *ever* use injection to insert static content, like in this example?

Comment: For static content, you got me...Maybe as a learning exercise.  I don't see any point in doing it versus just the basics.  It is just static content after all.

Comment: @primatology: Hi, I updated the contents page...in this case the only thing that I have to work with possibly is an existing @HtmlEditorFor() block (instead of static html content).

Comment: @TravisJ: Totally agree with your perspective!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Injection in my opinion is more expensive, it makes some javascript calls in your case. Injection maybe suitable when using templates of html (jquery.tmpl).